# Rspec uninitialized constant NameError, when not requiring Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to speed my tests up by not requiring Rails. Am moving things slowly into modules and testing separately. Things are faster, yay (if a little confusing)...

The only issue I have right now is when a module requires another module.

My guard tests pass however, when running rspec, I get the following:

```
uninitialized constant UserAlerts::UserMailerHelper (NameError)
```

My UserAlerts module looks like something like this:

```
module UserAlerts

  include UserMailerHelper

  def state_events(params)
    .. stuff ...
    state_events_email(emails, params)
  end

  def state_events_email(emails, params)
    emails.each do |email|
      send_message(email, params)
    end
  end
```

And my UserMailerHelper as so:

```
module UserMailerHelper

  def send_message(email, params={})
    send...
  end

end
```

In my spec/lib/user_alerts.rb test, I have something like this:

```
require File.expand_path("../../../app/lib/user_alerts", __FILE__)

class Biscuit
  include UserAlerts
end

describe UserAlerts do

  context "finds users to send emails to" do

    it "should return the users who get an email" do
      users = [stub(:email => email, beta: true, system_alerts: 'email'),
               stub(:email => email, beta: false, system_alerts: 'sms')]
      bis = Biscuit.new
      bis.stub(:users) { users }
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

I run rspec as follows:

```
rspec -I . ./spec/lib/user_alerts_spec.rb
```

What should I do to get rspec to pick up the module??

Comment: you also have to require that module. what is `app/lib` supposed to be?